# Laravel7 Load Yaml file as part of the config values

Tags: php, laravel, yaml

I have a laravel7 app.. it has the usual `config` folder with different files where i can use config values without a problem.. however, due to some devOps needs, i have to add a `yaml file` to the config folder and let's call it `abc.yml`.

I found easy ways to parse the yaml file and make it part of the normal config values fetched in laravelwithout a problem, like the following lines of code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

try {
    $abc = Yaml::parse($app->basePath('config/abc.yaml'));
    $app->make('config')->set('abc', $abc);
} catch (ParseException $exception) {
}
```

However, the challenge for me is where to put this code so that it runs upon loading the app and therefore when the app starts, I have my Yaml configs integrated as part of the normal laravel config values.

I have tried to put it inside `bootsrap/app.php` but it keeps giving me errors when running the artisan commands.. and also it doesn't look like the right place for it either.

looking forward to your suggestions

Comment: the `boot` method of a ServiceProvider is a good start ... though you may want to check if the configuration is already cached before loading the file `$this->app->configurationIsCached()`

Answer (score 0):

For my search on web I found this package [pragmarx/yaml](https://packagist.org/packages/pragmarx/yaml)

install it with

```
composer require pragmarx/yaml
```

and load the configuration in your app service provider in boot() method:

```php
Yaml::loadToConfig(config_path('abc.yml'), 'my-package');
```

And it's merged to your Laravel config:

```php
config('my-package.name');
```

Hope this package helps you